# Structure of RSA keys

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, pkcs#8

I'm trying to understand a structure of public and private keys. I generate RSA key's pair:

```
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        generator.initialize(2048, random);
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();         
        Key publicKey = pair.getPublic();
        Key privateKey = pair.getPrivate();             
        System.out.println("publicKey : " + byteArrayToHexString(publicKey.getEncoded()));          
        System.out.println("privateKey : " + byteArrayToHexString(privateKey.getEncoded()));
```

I use ASN.1 decoder to explore the structure of generated keys and I see that private key structure contains all elements of the public key structure. Why?

[Public key structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAgr.jpg)

[Private key structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTGvi.jpg)

Comment: Don't embed or link to images of text. Just copy and paste it into your question. If you're asking why the public and private RSA keys both contain the public exponent and modulus, then you really should just read up on how RSA works.

Comment: Just curious: Did you use http://lapo.it/asn1js/ to decode the ASN.1?

Comment: And, @Andrey, while reading up on RSA, make sure to check out what above commenter's user name refers to :-)

Answer (score 0):

The short reason a PKCS8 RSA privatekey contains these fields is because it uses (for RSA) the syntax defined way back around 1990 by the original standard *for* RSA, PKCS1, now available more conveniently as RFCs 2437 3447 and 8107, in section 11.1.2 or A.1.2 depending on version.

Yes there is some redundancy: n can easily be recomputed from p x q, and d mod both p-1 and q-1 can easily be recomputed from d or vice versa d from d mod p-1 and q-1, not to mention that either d or e can be computed from the other given p and q. Why what was then RSA Laboratories chose to store everything I don't know -- especially since it's relatively easy in ASN.1 to make things optional, and in some *other* (albeit later?) PKCS's they did.

For what it's worth the roughly contemporaneous PGP format does not store d mod p-1 and q-1, and uses p inverse mod q instead of vice versa. But PGP appends 'secretkey' (really privatekey) to publickey for *all* algorithms, thus it does have both n and p,q and both d and e.

Even though encountered in code this isn't really a question or problem about programming, and if you want to pursue it I recommend crypto.stackexchange.com instead.